# Meteor cursor ignores sort option

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, reactjs, meteor

I'm using `Meteor` with `React` and `react-meteor-data`. I'm trying to get the `Videos.find(...)` function to return an array sorted by it's 'index' field. See my code below.

The first `console.log()` prints the array properly sorted. The second `console.log()` prints the array in it's default order. Even if I change the sort option, it seems to be ignored. I am unable to figure out how to have that `videos` constant sorted.

```
export default DashboardContainer = createContainer(props => {
  const videosHandle = Meteor.subscribe('userVideos');
  const loading = !videosHandle.ready();
  const videos = !loading ? Videos.find({}, {fields: {title:1, subtitle:1,
    duration:1, thumb:1, url:1, index:1, groups:1}, sort: {index:1}}).fetch() : [];

  // logs the array properly sorted by the index field of the elements
  console.log(Videos.find({}, {fields: {title:1, subtitle:1, duration:1, thumb:1, url:1, index:1, groups:1}, sort: {index:1}}).fetch());

  // logs the array unsorted (unwanted behaviour)
  console.log(videos);

  return {
   loading,
   videos,
  };
}, Dashboard);
```

### Update:

If I use `console.log(videos.map((i) => i.index));` instead of `console.log(videos)`, I get the list printed in the correct order:

`[1,2,3,4,5...]`

Why?!